dotnet restore takes too much time (docker dotnet/sdk:8.0)
With dotnet/sdk:8.0, dotnet restore in a container takes way too much time (45 minutes to restore a project).
especially on The Gitlab-ci pipeline.

Set ENV DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false in your dockerfile.
something like this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyMicroservice.csproj .
ENV DOTNET_NUGET_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION=false
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyMicroservice.dll"]

